# When is the set values of of a set of functions evaluated at every point closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Suppose $\mathbb {F}\subset\{f:\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+:f \text{ is continuous and monotonic } \}$
What necessary conditions do we need to impose on $\mathbb {F}$ such that $\mathbb {X}=\{f(x):f \in \mathbb {F}\}$ is closed for every $x\in \mathbb R_+ $

I feel like this might have something to do with the closedness of $\mathbb {F}$, though I could not find a connection. I would be glad if you knew of a possible lead into answering this.

Comment: I would be open to an answer which would provide the set being open/ closed in some topology. If I were to choose I would say topology of compact convergence. If you tell me what you are thinking maybe we can discuss this.

Comment: The closedness with respect to what topology?

Comment: Yes, I could not think how closedness could come into play. I considered closedness with respect to the pointwise topology and the compact convergence one, but that did not lead to the answer.

Comment: It's an interesting question, please post an answer if you find a solution elsewhere.

Comment: Definitely. I will.

Comment: Do you require strict monotonicity?

Comment: Yes those are strictly monotonic functions.

Comment: Alright.  Do you want $\mathbb{X}(x)$ to be closed in $\mathbb{R}$ in its usual (metric) topology?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Well consider the functions $f_{\alpha}(x)=\alpha x$ with $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$.  This, along with the requirement of strict monotonicity, shows that $\mathbb{X}(x)=\mathbb{R}^+$ which is open in $\mathbb{R}$.  I can't think of (reasonable) conditions to impose on $\mathbb{F}$ that would remove all of these functions (or any other family of counterexamples), but I invite you to try.

Comment: Okay, so let us make it more tractable by imposing a further condition, for example, what if $f(x)\leq x$ for all x. That would make the question more precise. So, in this case, if the set of $\alpha$ is closed (which would make F closed too), we would have the answer.

Comment: With that additional requirement, we have $\mathbb{X}(x)=(0,x]$, which is still not closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hence, I mentioned "if the set of α is closed"!

Comment: Alright then consider the collection of functions $f_{\alpha,\beta}(x)=\alpha e^{\beta x}$ with $\alpha>0,\beta\neq0$.